# SELECT all rows for given start_datetime and end_datetime

Tags: mysql, database

i have this mysql table with following records.

table name : `gce_arena_surface_booking`

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | start_datetime      | end_datetime        | arena_surface_id |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 | 2012-11-22 02:30:00 | 2012-11-22 05:00:00 |                2 |
|  2 | 2012-11-22 00:00:00 | 2012-11-22 02:30:00 |                2 |
|  3 | 2012-11-22 05:00:00 | 2012-11-22 08:00:00 |                2 |
|  4 | 2012-11-22 08:00:00 | 2012-11-22 11:00:00 |                2 |
|  5 | 2012-11-22 11:00:00 | 2012-11-22 17:00:00 |                2 |
|  6 | 2012-11-22 17:30:00 | 2012-11-22 22:00:00 |                2 |
|  7 | 2012-11-23 02:00:00 | 2012-11-23 18:00:00 |                2 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

i need to know by given date time, if any booking already exist, i am using this query to check if any booking exist for given `start_datetime`, and `end_datetime`

```
SELECT 
    id, start_datetime, end_datetime, arena_surface_id 
FROM 
    gce_arena_surface_booking 
WHERE (
    (start_datetime BETWEEN '2012-11-23 2:00' AND '2012-11-23 6:00') OR 
    (end_datetime BETWEEN '2012-11-23 2:00' AND '2012-11-23 6:00')
) 
AND arena_surface_id = 2
```

the above query is giving me problems for example if i have the value changed from :

```
'2012-11-23 2:00' AND '2012-11-23 6:00'
```

to

```
'2012-11-23 2:30' AND '2012-11-23 6:00'
```

note that i have changed the value from `2:00` to `2:30`, it does not return me any result if i do that, whereas with reference to above records i expect it to return me a row with id `7` since i have the time slot booked in between `2:00` and and `18:00`, and hence any given value that matches time between `02:00` and `18:00` should be returning a row.

what would be the proper mysql query to deal with my problem?

here is the link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca82d/1) if you want to play around with records and schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bookings that starts when or after your new booking ends, or that ends when or before your new booking starts are no problem.

Thus the bookings you need to find are the ones that both starts before your new booking ends, and ends after your new booking starts.

Your query shoud then be

```
SELECT id, start_datetime, end_datetime, arena_surface_id 
FROM gce_arena_surface_booking 
WHERE ('2012-11-23 6:00' > start_datetime)
AND ('2012-11-23 2:00' < end_datetime)
AND arena_surface_id = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Query to find **overlapping bookings** is given below. Just need to add one more check to find if the slot we are searching is with in the already booked slot in database.
Its like both the start date and end date of search slot is with in the slot already booked.

```
SELECT 
    id, start_datetime, end_datetime, arena_surface_id 
FROM 
    gce_arena_surface_booking 
WHERE (
    (start_datetime BETWEEN '2012-11-23 2:30' AND '2012-11-23 6:00') OR 
    (end_datetime BETWEEN '2012-11-23 2:30' AND '2012-11-23 6:00')

  OR '2012-11-23 2:30' BETWEEN start_datetime AND end_datetime


) 
AND arena_surface_id = 2
```

If need to find out the **non overlapping slots** in database, use the below query. It is the negation of the above one.

```
SELECT * FROM `gce_arena_surface_booking`
WHERE (`arena_surface_id`=2)
AND
(start_datetime NOT BETWEEN '2012-11-23 02:30:00' AND '2012-11-23 06:00:00')
AND
(end_datetime NOT BETWEEN '2012-11-23 02:30:00' AND '2012-11-23 06:00:00')
AND
('2012-11-23 02:30:00' NOT BETWEEN start_datetime AND end_datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT 
        id, start_datetime, end_datetime, arena_surface_id 
    FROM 
        gce_arena_surface_booking 

    Where ('2012-11-23 2:30' between start_datetime and end_datetime)
    and ('2012-11-23 6:00' between start_datetime and end_datetime)
```

Comment: that does not work :(, @anand you can have a look at this link to see if it returns proper records. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca82d/1

Comment: what is end_time, and where is arena_surface_id condition?

Comment: the solution works with only one record, if i try to take value as `'2012-11-22 1:30'` , `'2012-11-22 4:00'` it returns with empty records, whereas it should be returning me two records, what could be wrong?